# How to Create captcha in asp.net core Asp.net Mvc 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, captcha

I am developing asp.net MVC 6 application in asp.net core , and i want to create a captcha for my login page. in previous .net frameworks i used the system.drawing to create a captcha but since in .net framework core we dont have system.drawing , how can i achieve this ?

one solution is to reference full .net framework but this is not what i want. i want to use the core framework.

another one is to create a project with .net framework 6 and Mvc 5 and use a web api to get the captcha image , but also this is not what i want.

is there another solution ?

Comment: whatever you do, don't use https://captcha.com/asp.net-captcha.html ... it causes Application Break mode :|

Answer (score 11):

I implemented Recaptcha in my ASP.NET Core apps. In my login view:

```
@if (Model.RecaptchaSiteKey.Length > 0)
{
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
}


@if (Model.RecaptchaSiteKey.Length > 0)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@Model.RecaptchaSiteKey"></div>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("recaptchaerror", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

I implemented an extension method on controller so I can validate the captcha server side easily from any controller where I'm using it.

```
public static async Task<RecaptchaResponse> ValidateRecaptcha(
    this Controller controller,
    HttpRequest request,
    string secretKey)
{
    var response = request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"];
    var client = new HttpClient();
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync(
        string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}",
            secretKey,
            response)
            );

    var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecaptchaResponse>(result);

    return captchaResponse;
}
```

Then this snippet from the login post method in my AccountController checks the captcha server side using that extension method:

```
if ((Site.CaptchaOnLogin) && (Site.RecaptchaPublicKey.Length > 0))
{
    var recpatchaSecretKey = Site.RecaptchaPrivateKey;
    var captchaResponse = await this.ValidateRecaptcha(Request, recpatchaSecretKey);

    if (!captchaResponse.Success)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("recaptchaerror", "reCAPTCHA Error occured. Please try again");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Note that to call extension methods on a controller you have to use the this keyword.

I'm using this in multiple projects currently so if you need to see more code, the most simple is in my [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.Web.SimpleAuth) project, but I'm also using it [cloudscribe](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe)

Comment: tnx for you solution. but i dont want to get the captcha image from different server, i want to create that in my project. at this moment i create another project ( a web api project ) that gives me a image . like the recaptcha that you suggest.

Comment: not sure if it is ready for use but maybe look at this https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor I know they are working on .NET Core support, not sure how far along they are

Comment: ImageProcessor is already supporting .NET Core. Unfortunately it isn't able (AFAIK) to draw, "only" manipulate existing images

Comment: We could use services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); in the ConfigureServices method and _accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(); in our PageModel to obtain the remoteIp to be sent to the recaptcha verify. Source https://edi.wang/post/2017/10/16/get-client-ip-aspnet-20

Answer (score 9):

I made a wrapper for recaptcha that works with aspnetcore, check it out https://www.nuget.org/packages/PaulMiami.AspNetCore.Mvc.Recaptcha and there is some documentation at https://github.com/PaulMiami/reCAPTCHA/wiki/Getting-started

In short you need to do the following to use it:

1. Setup the service in your your Startup class.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddRecaptcha(new RecaptchaOptions
    {
        SiteKey = Configuration["Recaptcha:SiteKey"],
        SecretKey = Configuration["Recaptcha:SecretKey"]
    });
}
```

2. In your "_ViewImports.cshtml" file add.

```
@addTagHelper *, PaulMiami.AspNetCore.Mvc.Recaptcha
```

3. In your view.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <recaptcha />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <recaptcha-script />
}
```

4. In your controller.

```
[ValidateRecaptcha]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: how would you change the error message for wrong recaptcha submissin?

Answer (score 4):

I've done this:

Add a reference to System.Drawing.Common

Install linux libs if on linux:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
sudo apt install libgdiplus
```

1. In AccountController

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCaptchaImage()
        {
            var validate = "";
            var bmp = ImageCaptcha.Generate(200, 150, out validate);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                SetCookie("CV", validate.Hash()+"");
                return File(ms.ToArray(),"image/png");
            }
        }

        // move to base controller
        public void SetCookie(string key, string value, int? expireTime = null)
        {
            CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

            if (expireTime.HasValue)
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
            else
                option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(5 * 60 * 1000);

            Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
        }
```

Add this class to project - generates random rotated letters bmp in mem:

```
public static class ImageCaptcha
    {

        public static Bitmap Generate(int w, int h, out string validate)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            var brush = new[] { Brushes.Brown, Brushes.LawnGreen, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Coral};
            var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            validate = null;
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    var text = Convert.ToChar( rand.Next(97, 122)).ToString();
                    validate += text;
                    if(i==0) g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
                    g.RotateTransform(40 * 5 * rand.Next(1, 6));
                    var font = new Font("Arial", h * 0.25f + 8 * rand.Next(1, 6), FontStyle.Bold);
                    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);
                    g.DrawString(text, font, brush[i],15*(i+1) -(textSize.Width / 2), -(textSize.Height / 2));
                }
            }

            return bmp;
        }

    }
```

Add this utility class to get md5 hash easy:

```
public static partial class H
{
    public static int Hash(this string value)
    {
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        var hashed = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
        var ivalue = BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0);
        return ivalue;
    }
}
```

2. Change Register action to this, see comments - added, changed:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            var validCaptchaText = Request.Cookies["cv"]; //added
            if (ModelState.IsValid && model.UserCaptchaText.Hash()+""==validCaptchaText) //changed
            {
                var user = new AppUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

3. In register view after "ConfirmPassword"

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Captcha</label><br />
                    <img style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #ced4da" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetCaptchaImage")" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
                        <li style="width:24px;height:12px; display:inline-block; background-color:#a52a2a "></li>
                        <li style="width:24px;height:12px; display:inline-block; background-color:#7cfc00 "></li>
                        <li style="width:24px;height:12px; display:inline-block; background-color:#0000ff "></li>
                        <li style="width:24px;height:12px; display:inline-block; background-color:#ff7f50 "></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="UserCaptchaText"></label>
                    <input asp-for="UserCaptchaText" class="form-control" />
                </div>

                <button style="color:white; background-color:#4a7dbc" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
```

And done.

Comment: It seems it is not working anymore in dotnet7 and later. System.Drawing.Common is not supported on Linux. so is there any other suggestion about generating captcha image in dotnet7?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without any special packaging. According to the recaptcha site -

**Client Side Integration**

Paste this snippet before the closing `</head>` tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOURSITEKEY"></div>
```

**Server Side Integration**

When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll get as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". In order to check whether Google has verified that user, send a POST request with these parameters:

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

secret (required): YOURSECRETKEY

response (required): The value of 'g-recaptcha-response'.

remoteip: The end user's ip address.

Comment: as i did mention in my question , i created a different project and implement the way you described with my own servers, but i want to get the captcha in mvc 6 and with new .net new technology( asp.net core)

Comment: The method I described works in MVC 6 and .NET Core. I am running it already. If you are looking for a Nuget package, I was able to get the package created by @PaulMiami to work as well.

Comment: you make a request to a web api and get the image , and also for checking the correctness of captcha you make another  request the web api and they did the work for you, i know this and i implement it with my own web api. what i want is to use an alternative lib for system.draw. because .net core did not implement it.

Comment: would not the [data-sitekey="YOURSITEKEY"] attribute be visible in the page source for someone else to use?

Answer (score 1):

To easy, you can user that component, You can see how use in that link
https://www.nuget.org/packages/IgniteCaptcha/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to create Captcha in Mvc.

1. Add the CaptchaMvc library to the Reference Layer in your application like this.
2. Now create the Index View like this.

View

```
 @using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers  
 @using MathCaptcha;  
 @using CaptchaMvc;  

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {  
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  

<fieldset>  
    <legend>Captcha Example</legend>  

    @Html.MathCaptcha()  

    @*@Html.Captcha(3)*@  

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />  

 </fieldset>  
 }
```

@Html.MathCaptcha() helper class then it will generate a mathmatical CAPTCHA. If you using the @Html. Captcha(3) helper class then it will generate a Char CAPTCHA. 3 is the length of the CAPTCHA.

3. In the post action method I wrote code for CAPTCHA validation.

   ```
    [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult Index(string empty)  
    {  
       // Code to validate the CAPTCHA image
       if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha not valid"))  
       {  

           // do your stuff  
       }  

       return View();  
    }
   ```

Comment: I am using the new version of .net framework . your solution is for mvc 5 not mvc 6.